# IfNull function in mysql doesnt seem to work for me

Tags: mysql, ifnull

IfNull function in mysql doesnt seem to work for me.... When i executed this query

```
select t1.dAccHeader_id,t1.dAccHeaderName,t1.dAccHeaderAcronym,
t2.dDesignationName as incharge1,
t3.dDesignationName as incharge2,t4.dDesignationName as incharge3
from tbl_accountheader as t1
inner join tbl_designation_master as t2 on t2.dDesignation_id = t1.dPaymentIncharge_1
inner join tbl_designation_master as t3 on t3.dDesignation_id = ifnull(t1.dPaymentIncharge_2,'0')
inner join tbl_designation_master as t4 on t4.dDesignation_id = ifnull(t1.dPaymentIncharge_3,'0')
and t1.dCollege_id='1'
and t1.dIsDelete='0'
```

Here is my table,

[image: My Table]

Any sugesstion...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function

```
inner join tbl_designation_master as t3 
      on t3.dDesignation_id = coalesce(t1.dPaymentIncharge_2,'0')
```

*if your id is a number you can also remove the quote*:

```
coalesce(t1.dPaymentIncharge_2, 0)
```

Check also if your `t1.dPaymentIncharge_1` can be null